# R - Singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates

Tags: r, nls

I'm trying to fit a harmonic equation to my data, but when I'm applying the `nls` function, R gives me the following error:

> Error in nlsModel(formula, mf, start, wts) : singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates.

All posts I've seen, related to this error, are of exponential functions, where a linearization is used to fix this error, but in this case, I'm not able to solve it in this way. I tried to use other starting points but it still not working.

**CODE:**

```
y <- c(20.91676, 20.65219, 20.39272, 20.58692, 21.64712, 23.30965, 23.35657, 24.22724, 24.83439, 24.34865, 23.13173, 21.96117)
t <- c(1, 2, 3, 4 , 5 , 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)


# Fitting function

fit <- function(x, a, b, c) {a+b*sin(2*pi*x)+c*cos(2*pi*x)}

res <- nls(y ~ fit(t, a, b, c), data=data.frame(t,y), start = list(a=1,b=0, c=1))
```

Can you help me? Thanks!

Comment: Could you include an example data that yields this error? Could be with only the first few lines of your data for example, or some fake data.

Comment: Sure! I edited the post in order to give the numeric example. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems:

1. `cos(2*pi*t)` is a vector of all ones for the `t` given in the question so the model is not identifiable given that there is already an intercept
2. the model is linear in the parameters so one can use `lm` rather than `nls` and no starting values are needed
3. the model does not work well even if we address those points as seen by the large second coefficient.  Improve the model.

```
lm(y ~ sin(2*pi*t))
```

giving:

```
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ sin(2 * pi * t))

Coefficients:
    (Intercept)  sin(2 * pi * t)  
      2.195e+01       -2.262e+14
```

Instead try this model using the plinear algorithm which does not require starting values for the parameters that enter linearly.  This implements the model `.lin1 + .lin2 * cos(a * t + b)` where the .lin1 and .lin2 parameters are implicit parameters that enter linearly and don't need starting values.

```
fm <- nls(y ~ cbind(1, cos(a * t + b)), start = list(a = 1, b = 1), alg = "plinear")

plot(y ~ t)
lines(fitted(fm) ~ t, col = "red")

fm
```

giving:

```
Nonlinear regression model
  model: y ~ cbind(1, cos(a * t + b))
   data: parent.frame()
      a       b   .lin1   .lin2 
 0.5226  4.8814 22.4454 -2.1530 
 residual sum-of-squares: 0.7947

Number of iterations to convergence: 9 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 8.865e-06
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for your help and the excellent explanation! I used the  ```nls``` function for all linear and non-linear equations because so far it has been working properly for me, but in this case, I converted the real-time vector to simple numbers and did not realize the absurd mistake.